# Cannot find custom extension namespace in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to create some method extensions for database so in VS2010 I created a class `DataBaseExtensions` in same project with

```
namespace CustomDatabaseExtensions
{
    public static class DataBaseExtensions
    {
```

But in my ASP.NET C# code, using `CustomDatabaseExtensions` is not accepted as `CustomDatabaseExtensions` could not be found.

I tried to put the class in `App_Code` but nothing changed.

What's wrong? Should I add a reference or something like that even if my class is in the same project ?

In case it matters I'm on windows 8 32 bits, build is for any cpu

Comment: is `CustomDatabaseExtensions` in the same ASP.NET project?

Comment: http://manoj-adventurecontinues.blogspot.com/2009/01/adding-namespace-in-aspnet-or-c.html

Comment: @robert yes it's in same project (I updated)

Comment: Intellisense in code-behind files can be a bit dicey.  Did you include the namespace like the link above describes, and did you do it even though it didn't intellisense?

Comment: i read your article I learnt the 4th way thanks, but I can't see you mention intellisense. But in my case Intellisense doesn't show the namespace. Should I add a reference or something like that even if my class is in the same project ?

Comment: Show the declaration of at least one of your extension methods, and how you are using it in your code, where it is that you get an error message, and what that message exactly is.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Website, the correct folder for place your class is `App_Code`, and not `App_Data`.
Otherwise, if your project is a Webapplication (with "Properties" project folder) the class can be placed everywhere, but not into `App_Data`.

Hope this help!

Comment: sorry I meant App_Code not App_Data.

Comment: In some cases, if your site contains code-behind errors (in .aspx.cs or .ascx.cs or .master.cs files), or markup errors (in .aspx, .ascx, .master files), visual studio don't show all project namespaces in the intellisense. If you exclude the extension class and compile, there is a compilation error? Look also into the compilation output window